# Pause bootstrap carousel at specified resolution

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-carousel

I'm trying to pause the bootstrap carousel at any resolution below 640px. I've tried a number of different seemingly intuitive ways to do this but nothing is working.

Currently I have:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        if ($(window).width() > 640) {
            $('.carousel').carousel('pause');
        } else {
            $('.carousel').carousel();
        };
```

});

Comment: This does only attempt to pause the carousel once on page load.  Are you testing it by resizing your browser without reloading?  It's more robust to tie this kind of action into a `$(window).on('resize', function(){ ... })` event listener.

Comment: I've tested it both by resizing and by reloading. Very strange. Seems like it must be something other than jquery...

Comment: Where are you testing it?  Is it on your own environment, on jsfiddle, or in bootply?  I can't seem to get `pause` to work in bootply, but that could just be because it's iframed in (or at least I'm assuming it is).

Comment: I got it working but only after wrapping it in a `load` event listener for the window.  http://www.bootply.com/JxL8isRuQR.  Edit: [viewing it on codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/JxL8isRuQR) makes it easier to resize the screen.

Comment: with a (window).on("load"... does one still need a (document).ready(... if the script is embedded in the html?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the `'cycle'` attribute inside your else statement for the carousel to start.
I also included a commented `.on` listener just in case you want to actively check for width changes. For example if the user resize the window.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     //$(window).on( "resize", function(){
            if ($(window).width() > 640) {
                $('.carousel').carousel('pause');
            } else {
                $('.carousel').carousel('cycle');
            }
         //console.log($(window).width());
      //})
     });
```